# Hidden Textarea Options Showing with Other Options When Submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have made a request PHP form with many select options. One of the select options is name employee to which one of its text area i pre-typed text and selected  `type="hidden"`  as shown in form. The problem is when I submit the form request from another select option for example if I select option IT Request from the form and fill its input and submit it & when I get results in HTML email I also get the hidden text area texts that were pre type for Employee select option and it also shows with the tv request details

Also, how can I submit the HTML table in form? Right now I’m doing double work. First, create the hide/show table for users to see and same time I a have hidden text area containing the same data so when the user selects an option from hide/show HTML table it’s submitted it sends the same text pre typed to email

See the [image]image attached i sent a example request from the working form. It is mixing two options. I sent a IT Request and it is mixing the Employee Hidden Textarea

```js
function EmployeeGroup() {
  var groups = document.getElementById("groups"); {
    var ITRequest = document.getElementById("ITRequest");
    ITRequest.style.display = groups.value == "IT" ? "block" : "none";
  } {
    var Employee = document.getElementById("Employee");
    Employee.style.display = groups.value == "EmpGM" ? "block" : "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testbox">
  <form name="frmContact" id="frmContact" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="p-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select a Category</label>
      <select id="groups" name="groups" class="form-control w-100" required onchange="EmployeeGroup()">
        <option value="">--Select an option--</option>
        <option value="ITRequest">IT Request</option>
        <option value="Employee">New Hire</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="EmpGM">
      <h2>Requestor's Information</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userReqEmp">Requestor Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userReqEmp" name="userReqEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userNameEmp">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userNameEmp" name="userNameEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userComEmp">Comments (Optional)</label>
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userComEmp" name="userComEmp" rows="7" placeholder="Type Here..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-12" for="userEIDEmp">Employee ID</label>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userEIDEmp" name="userEIDEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-12" for="userOIDEmp">One ID</label>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userOIDEmp" name="userOIDEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-12" for="userDateEmp">Start Date</label>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <input type="date" class="form-control w-100" id="userDateEmp" name="userDateEmp" placeholder="Type Here...">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <!--GM Group -->
          <textarea style="visibility:hidden;" class="textarea" id="acc_GMGroup" name="acc_GMGroup" rows="5">
<u>Domain Group Access:</u>
All Access Folders

<u>Distribution List:</u>
All Manager Emails

<u>Additional Access</u>
VPN Non-Standard
                        </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-12">Select Department</label>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <select id="groups" name="groups" class="form-control w-100">
                <option selected value="">Select an option</option>
                <option value="GM">GM</option>
                <option value="AGM">AGM</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <!-- GM -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" id="groups_GM" name="groups_GM" style="display: none;">
              <h2>DC GM Group</h2>
              <table class="tb">
                <tr>
                  <th>Domain Group Access</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>All Access Folders</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Distribution List</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>All Manager Emails</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Additional Access</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>VPN Non-Standard</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--  General IT  Request  -->

    <div class="form-group" id="IT">
      <h2>IT Service Request</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <label for="userITRequest">Requestor Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userITRequest" name="userITRequest" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-6">
          <label>Select your Department</label>
          <select id="groups" name="groups" class="form-control w-100">
            <option selected value="">Select an option</option>
            <option value="HR">HR</option>
            <option value="MPB">MPB</option>
            <option value="Management">Management</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="userITSubject">Subject</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userITSubject" name="userITSubject" placeholder="Type Here...">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="userITMessage">Messages</label>
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control w-100" id="userITMessage" name="userITMessage" rows="7" placeholder="Type Here..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="myfile"><strong>Choose a file to upload</strong></label>
          <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

```
 $userEmpReq = clean($_POST["userReqEmp"]);
$userEmpName = clean($_POST["userNameEmp"]);
$userEmpDate = clean($_POST["userDateEmp"]);
$userEmpEID = clean($_POST["userEIDEmp"]);
$userEmpOID = clean($_POST["userOIDEmp"]);
isset($_POST["groups"]) ? $groupNew = clean($_POST["groups"]) : $groupNew = "";
$usersGMGroup = nl2br($_POST["acc_GMGroup"]);                                        // DC GM Group  --  $usersGMGroup = nl2br($_POST["acc_GMGroup"]);
$usersAGMGroup = nl2br($_POST["acc_AGMGroup"]);
isset($_POST["select-9"]) ? $select9 = clean($_POST["select-9"]) : $select9 = "";
$userEmpManger = clean($_POST["userManagerEmp"]);
$userEmpCom = clean($_POST["userComEmp"]);
```

Comment: Any field in a form with a `name` attribute will be submitted. If you don't want a specific field (e.g. the hidden one) to be submitted, then remove it's `name` attribute in the html.

Comment: it works, But when i remove the name from the hidden textarea , the hidden textarea text does not submit with the at all

Comment: Ok I suppose I dont see or understand your question on the first part. What is the desired behavior you want?

Comment: For Example when i submit the request for the IT and when i get the email IT request form along with the details if IT i get the Employee details only the hidden ones BUT i did as you said but when i submit the employee request i dont get the hidden for employee which i should be getting it

Comment: @GetSet if you see the image attached thats what i mean when the text area has `<textarea style="visibility:hidden;" class="textarea" id="acc_GMGroup" name="acc_GMGroup" rows="2">` but when i remove the  `name="acc_GMGroup"` it doesnt submit anything or show anything for the Employee from the hidden textarea

Comment: How can I make the hidden textarea with name attribute to send HTML email-only to its assigned id or group? Right now when i submit other request apart from the hidden textarea it.. the hidden textarea text shows together when i submit the other request